# Is it possible to start Ethereum Wallet in --light mode by default on my Mac?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, light-clients

I mean without using Terminal geth each time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to forward arguments to geth via the ethereum wallet by using the `--node-` prefix .

Use the following command to start the wallet in light mode.

```
./ethereumwallet --node-light
```

It connects instantly.

Comment: how do you do that with the executable, which is in Applications/Ethereum Wallet.app

Comment: in cmd drag your ethereumwallet exe to get its path and write the light option then run  it

Comment: the question is about Mac not about windows exe. So, how can be done on mac?

Comment: This answer needs updating- `--node-light` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac the command from the terminal is (from the Applications folder) :

```
open "Ethereum Wallet.app" --args --node-light
```

There are some conflicts right now you might need to be aware:

https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2254